# No se puede asignar a la propiedad o el indizador

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código que recorre un DataGridView  el identificar me sale que es de solo lectura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo solucione de la siguiente forma antes no tenia el SET

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me empezó a salir lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo solucione de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero luego de que este dato pasa por acá me llega null " ", cuando desde el principio tenia un valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en el set no estás seteando el valor a `vendor.identification`. Tendrías que realizar lo siguiente:

```
public string identificador
{
   get { ... }
   set {
      if (vendor != null) {
         vendor.identification = value;
      }
   }
}
```